# Value of Green as Multiplier for an Inductor Color code

Tags: inductor, inductance, colour, colour-coding

I was going through the Internet searching for the Color code table for an Inductor. 
The more or less same table which I got is : 
[image]

I have got an inductor  : 
[image]

So I cannot find out the Value of this inductor because Green as a multiplier in the table is left blank. Is the Color coding on the inductor wrong? What is it's value?

Comment: Your photo shouts to me "1M resistor!" (1x10^6 ohms). How many ohms does an ohmmeter measure?

Comment: Variable. In 2M range,  it first begins from out of range (>2M) and then decreases relatively fast at first and then gradually decreases slowly.  I waited for 20Seconds, it decreased to 0.8M and was still decreasing.

Comment: One is tempted to hold ohmmeter probe leads against resistor leads with finger pressure to assure electrical contact - this will give you a reading that is on the low side, and varies (because you are measuring skin resistance). Hold the ohmmeter leads by their insulating body only, and keep your fingers off the metal probe tips.

Comment: Looks like resistor to me too. Never seen 1h axials. Although the behavior when measuring resistance seem to hint at inductor. Strange

Comment: Have you tested this with an ohm meter? That is always the first step

Comment: I can't imagine that's anything but a resistor from the picture either, but that's fine because the color code is the same other than base unit.  The table is just incomplete and if you wish you can fill the column with powers of 10.  That does sound like an inductor in performance, but I have some pretty slow ohmmeters.  Can you connect it with alligator clips perhaps or do you have a known 1M resistor you can compare against?